# Is unbeatable game state possible?

Tags: papers-please

I managed to get through the first days at relative ease. After several attempts, I can't earn enough money on the day I'm at to feed and medicate my family. 
Is a stalemate situation possible?

Comment: It sounds like you're asking if the state your game is in is possible to be in, which is confusing. Can you try to rephrase your question?

Comment: I think it would be better, if you'd just describe the situation you're in. I can't tell for certain, if there's a theoretical possibility for an unwinnable position. On one hand, the money you get depends on how fast you process people. On the other hand, you can be in a situation where everything has just gone wrong.

Comment: I'm not sure if it's possible to enter such a state, but in case you didn't know, I wanted to point out that you can continue from earlier days as well. If your game was saved after day 10 and you feel like you can't survive day 11, you can select day 9 or 8 and continue from there.

Comment: @MatthiasFischer: I'll edit my question to clarify.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, it is entirely possible to play the game without making any mistakes. See [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DWvzPU2sgsM) (I didn't watch it, but it claims to be a perfect playthrough).

As Matthias noted in a [comment](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/300948/is-unbeatable-game-state-possible#comment435930_300948), you are not expected to be able to always play from the latest day and get further. There are some situations where because of a past action, you will be arrested, or your family will die, or some other ending. You are encouraged to continue from a previous day or begin a new game and attempt to reach a different ending.

Comment: Can you tell about situations that result in game over?

Comment: @user598527 No, that's outside the scope of the question, and basically constitutes spoiling the entire game (every ending is game over).

Comment: If you're interested in the endings, check the [wiki](http://papersplease.wikia.com/wiki/Endings) (spoilers, of course).

Answer (score 2):

It is entirely practical for a skilled player to correctly process 15 applicants in a day (or 17 and 2 citations), earning the 75 credits required to feed 5 family members and rent a class 5 apartment.

Though this is an interesting question- is a softlock possible? For purposes of the question, this means a setup which will always end in ending 1 or 2.

Days with scripted attacks end after a specified number of migrants. So is it possible for there not to be enough, with zero savings and a single, very sick son?

If the inspector is in a class 8 apartment, he only needs 30 credits- 25 for rent and 5 to treat his son. No terrorist event allows fewer than six applicants. Additionally, the inspector can get 20 credits for shooting a terrorist.

If the inspector is in a better apartment, moving back to class 8 will become available earning 75 credits.

Comment: Day 28 has the earliest scripted attack, after the 6th entrant. You still have enough time to process a 7th if you're fast, and you might have to just take a guess, but it's possible. So you earn 35 credits that day. Rent costs 25, so you have 10 credits available. Very sick family members need two out of the three heat, food, and medicine to stay alive another day. With TWO very sick family members, paying for food/heat each costs 10 and medicine for one of them is 5, forcing you to spend at least 15 credits to keep one of them alive. Softlock.

Comment: @BryanAllaire 20 credit sharpshooter bonus.

Comment: Ah, that's right. It would have to be on day 2, 6, or 12, before you have the key. Days 6 and 12 each allow you to process 10, and day 2 is closer, only allowing you to process 7, but rent is only 20 and you can't set up sick family members in time anyway. I'd say it's impossible then.

Comment: @BryanAllaire I do want to double check if the downgrade is guaranteed but redoing the maths it doesn't seem to matter. Your worst case scenario gives you 55 credits (7 entrants, 20 sharpshooter).

Comment: Downgrade is guaranteed if you have under 20 credits in savings. See this post: https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/383610/how-does-papers-please-decide-when-to-offer-better-apartments/404184#404184